# How to change the log4j level for map reduce function in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, log4j

As the title, How can I change the log4j level for map reduce function in hadoop by passing parameter to command line. I don't want to change the level in programmatical way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should implement ToolRunner. In Hadoop Definitive guide there is a chapter describing it, [source](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/software-engineering-and-development/9781449328917/setting-up-the-development-environment/id4613268)

Comment: I read that chapter, but could not find how to set the log4j level. Could you point me where's the sample code ?

Comment: You are right there is not such info there. Have you tried add to the command line  "-D hadoop.root.logger = INFO"